# Granting rights to the sa account using osql

Tags: sql-server, osql

I'm installing sql instances through script, and after creating a certain instance, I cannot get the sa account to be enabled through osql.

What I've tried

1. osql -S .\INSTANCENAME -E
   use master
   ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE
   GO

   - Using SSMS to enable the account (by logging in using Windows Auth., 'New query', and exactly the same query as in 1.)
   - Suggestions in [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/35505/cant-connect-to-sql-server-using-sa-account-what-im-missing)

No. 2. is actually working; and the account is enabled instantly. No 1 is not working, not even with the suggestions provided in 3., I have restarted the SQL services after executing the commands in osql.

*Additional info*
Windows 2003 Server, Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Enterprise, No password policies apply to the account.

Comment: Do you get an error from #1?

Comment: Chris' answer is likely the problem; when you install you need to specify mixed mode and set the password.  If SA is disabled right after an install then mixed mode is not turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Is mixed mode enabled?

[Choosing an Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)

[To enable mixed mode authentication...](http://www.hostmysite.com/support/vps/windows/mixedmode/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not state, but the syntax .\instancename implies that you are running your OSQL on your target server?  Is this the case?  Have you tried Servername\instancename?